# Keeping only date in a timestamp while joinng to date in another table

Tags: date, timestamp, dbvisualizer

I am working with some tricky data, and am trying to join a timestamp to a date while getting rid of the timestamp all together and just keeping the date. I have tried a few different methods, but this is the most recent:

```
convert(row_add_ts, convert(date, current_timestamp)) as Row_add_ts
```

this is what the data looks like currently:

> 2017-01-01 00:00:08

this is how I want it to look:

> 2017-01-01

The join that I currently have looks like:

`Left outer join Table 2 b
 on a.row_adds_ts = b.Table_date`

I keep getting different errors, but the most recent is:

> [Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=DATE, DRIVER=4.19.49. 2) [Code: -514, SQL State: 26501]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=4.19.49

It looks like it is failing to convert the timestamp data type over to a date data type. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

I have also tried:

```
left(cast(row_adds_ts as date), 10)
```

to no prevail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the below query worked to give me what I was looking for:

```
Date(row_add_ts)
```